# jQuery: drag and drop folder slideshow for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slideshow

I'm creating a website for my organization that needs to have a slideshow for images.  We do not often have quality access to internet, and the folks maintaining the site won't be highly knowledgeable in web design, so updating frequently is difficult. Therefor I am trying to generate an image slideshow that will pull images from a specific folder on the server.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/581747/jQuery-Slideshow-for-a-selected-folder?fid=1831110&select=4601478&fr=1

This appears to do just that, however I don't know fully what I'm doing.  The guide says to place the HTML snippets in the head and body, that much is easy.

Next it states that a "simple sub" is to be created, and the following code is given...

```
Dim oDir As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("<relative path the images>"))
Dim fileList() As FileInfo = oDir.GetFiles("*.jpg")
Dim iFileCount As Integer = fileList.Count
iFileCount -= 1
Dim oImage As HtmlImage
For i As Integer = 0 To iFileCount
    oImage = New HtmlImage
    With oImage
        .Src = String.Format("path\{0}", fileList(i))
        If i = 0 Then .Attributes.Add("class", "active")
    End With
    slideshow.Controls.Add(oImage)
Next
```

I understand that "relative path the images" and "path" need to be updated with the name of the folder on my server... but I don't know what exactly to do with this code snippet.  Does it get saved as a new .js file? I'm not seeing anything in the HTML that references another file.

Also... That guide uses a jquery API hosted on codeproject.com... I'm assuming its safe to sub it out for the same one hosted with google? I'd prefer not to rely on codeproject.com.

Comment: That code is `VB.net` (server side) code. What kind of server do you have?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  its a FTP web server as far as I know.

Sorry if that's not what you're after.  I'm learning while doing right now, so I've got gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: when you purchased your hosting account, you probably ended up with a Windows server or a Linux server. Generally the shared host accounts tend to be Linux, and support PHP out of the box. The code snippet you found is Windows (.net) specific. PHP and .NET are (in layman's terms) 2 different languages you can program your "server-side" code with.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow

```
1. Open your aspx/HTML page (your code sounds as if it's an aspx page)
2. With in the head/body paste the two javascript <script>...</script> tags codeproject has mentioned.
3. Do the same for the CSS which is within <style>...</style> tag
4. Drag and Drop an HTMLImage control to your webpage and name it slideshow
5. Your Sub needs to live on the page to populate the HTMLImage control with the images.
```

Important to check if your HTMLImage control is loaded with all the images. If you are using Chrome to test the website, hit F12 and look for your control under the tab called "elements". If the HTMLImage control contains all the server side images, the 1-3 steps mentioned above should be sufficient.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm still not sure what I'm doing with that code snippet.  I'm assuming that's the HTMLImage control you're talking about.

Should I paste that into a text editor and name it slideshow?  What extension?

Comment: OK, tried creating a file with that code, naming it slideshow.aspx and that's not right.

I feel like this is easy and I'm just not getting it.  For background... I'm a photographer and layout designer (lots of Adobe Suite experience).

Comment: The code snippet is only to create the HTML elements that can hold your pictures in the slideshow. What language are you using to write your code? Are you trying to achieve this using HTML, CSS and jQuery only or vb.net(in aspx)?

Comment: Whatever works is what I want to use.

I'm creating this site in HTML and CSS like any other site... Used Muse to create the design, and I'm patching in fixes for things I need any way I can.

I chose that guide because it seemed like it does what I need. I may need to google around some more to figure this out. If anyone has seen something like this before, a push in the right direction would be great.

Comment: did you get a chance to try the code I have pasted above? Save it as an HTML file and change the src in the img tag as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below mentioned code. Edit the  tag at the bottom end of the code and add the link yo your image file within src="". This slideshow rotates every 7 due to accessibility reasons. You could change it to a different value in case you would like to do so.  Please let me know if you are still having trouble fixing this!

`

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /***
         Simple jQuery Slideshow Script
         Released by Jon Raasch (jonraasch.com) under FreeBSD license: free to use or modify,
         not responsible for anything, etc.  Please link out to me if you like it :)
         ***/

        function slideSwitch() {
            var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

            if ($active.length == 0)
                $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

            // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
            var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

            // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

            // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
            // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
            // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );

            $active.addClass('last-active');

            $next.css({
                opacity : 0.0
            }).addClass('active').animate({
                opacity : 1.0
            }, 1000, function() {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            });
        }

        $(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                console.log("fsdfsdf");
                slideSwitch();
            }, 7000);
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*** set the width and height to match your images **/

        #slideshow {
            position: relative;
            height: 350px;
            width: 350px;
        }

        #slideshow IMG {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 8;
            opacity: 0.0;
            height: 350px;
            width: 350px;
        }

        #slideshow IMG.active {
            z-index: 10;
            opacity: 1.0;
        }

        #slideshow IMG.last-active {
            z-index: 9;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="http://www.tate.org.uk/art/images/work/D/D29/D29293_10.jpg" alt="Picture 1" class="active">
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_ShpNcCZ0lVE/S_n3Xkv126I/AAAAAAAABbs/T0B8xwIg7Ko/s1600/IMG_7163.JPG" alt="Picture 2">
        <img src="http://www.automotofoto.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Honda-World-Superbike-Team-Heads-Home-for-Round-Three-THUMBNAIL-2.jpg" alt="Picture 3">
    </div>
</body>
```

`